# where to put code that operates on an array of structs?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

If I have a struct and some code that processes arrays of this struct, where would be the place to put this code?

```
struct Thing {
    var id : String
    let type : ThingType
}

things:[Thing]?
```

I have code to retrieve values from a server which returns an array of `100 Thing`. Where should the code go?

I've currently defined it as a static function of the Struct but would like to follow a convention, if there is one.

Comment: This completely depends on what "processes" entails.

Comment: how about, @AlexanderMomchliov, for the example I give about a server call returning a [Thing]

Comment: Generally, the code that performs server communication should be separate from data transfer objects (DTOs) which your struct represents.

Comment: That most certainly should not be a member of `Thing`. It's best to make a new protocol that declares the function, and have a new conforming struct/class which implements it. This way, you can change the provider you use (Firebase, Parse, SQLite, CoreData, JSON, CSV, whatever.) by just swapping out the concrete provider class you use

Comment: This also has the benefit that it allows you to make a mock implementation of the provider, which allows you to have unit tests that work independently from your production backend.

Comment: thanks. two great points.

Comment: I'll write it up in an answer in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function that retrieves `Thing` instances from a server most certainly should not be a member of Thing.

It's best to make a new protocol that declares the function, like so:

```
protocol ThingProvider {
    func fetchThings() -> [Thing]
}
```

and a conforming type:

```
class DataBaseThingProvider: ThingProvider {

    init() {
        // open database connection
    }

    deinit() {
        // close database connection
    }

    func fetchThings() -> [Thing] {
        // fetch Things from database
    }
}
```

This way, you can change the provider you use (Firebase, Parse, SQLite, CoreData, JSON, CSV, whatever.) by just swapping out the concrete provider class you use, and all other code can stay the same.

It also makes your code much more testable, because you can easily construct a mock provider, which decouples your tests from your production backend.

```
class MockThingProvider: ThingProvider {

    func fetchThings() -> [Thing] {
        return [
            Thing(id: "MockThing1", type: thingType1),
            Thing(id: "MockThing2", type: thingType2),
            Thing(id: "MockThing3", type: thingType3)
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @AlexanderMomchliov. Any reason you choose a class for DataBaseThingProvider over a struct? (have gotten message that Swift can be more robust with structs wrt memory leaks)

Comment: Because database connections (logically speaking) shouldn't be copied on assignment. What have you heard about memory leaks in Swift?

Comment: Swift closures are getting a reputation. E.g. "Closures are very tricky because they have ‘capture semantics" @ http://leojkwan.com/2016/02/memory-leaks

Comment: Well yeah, you have to avoid reference cycles, which is especially true when dealing with `self` in stored closures. That doesn't mean you should entirely avoid classes. They have their uses. In this case, I'd prefer there to be a single object per database connection, so I opted for a class

Comment: Perhaps a singleton struct to enforce that single object per database connection?

Comment: or, back with a class: http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

Comment: @Carl Yep. I would use a singleton. However, singletons can't be implemented via structs. Just by doing `let x = MyStruct.shared` you're creating a copy from `shared` to `x`. You already have 2 instances, just by doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129469/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-carl).